# How to store nested object data in database vue.js project. ( which format?)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a project in which I am creating data in nested object and while storing it in database I am doing  JSON.stringify. Its all working fine but when I am tying to fetch same data from database I need to json.parse but after that i am assigning it to a vuex state I losing some nested data from my original  data.

data in data base:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1-368",
    "name": "\tSolan",
    "days": 1,
    "daynights": 2,
    "hotel": {
      "hotel_data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "hotel 1"
        }
      ],
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "hotel2": {
      "hotel_data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "hotel 1"
        }
      ],
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "specinst": "",
    "mealplan": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "2-54",
    "name": "Dharamsala",
    "days": "3",
    "daynights": 4,
    "hotel": {
      "hotel_data": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "hotel3"
        }
      ],
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "hotel2": {
      "hotel_data": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "hotel 2"
        }
      ],
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "specinst": "",
    "mealplan": ""
  }
]
```

data after assigning to vuex state:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1-368",
    "name": "\tSolan",
    "days": 1,
    "daynights": 2,
    "hotel": {
      "hotel_data": "",
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "hotel2": {
      "hotel_data": "",
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "specinst": "",
    "mealplan": "",
    "date_from": "08 Jan 2020",
    "date_to": "09 Jan 2020"
  },
  {
    "id": "2-54",
    "name": "Dharamsala",
    "days": "3",
    "daynights": 4,
    "hotel": {
      "hotel_data": "",
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "hotel2": {
      "hotel_data": "",
      "checkin": "",
      "checkout": "",
      "roomtype": ""
    },
    "specinst": "",
    "mealplan": "",
    "date_from": "09 Jan 2020",
    "date_to": "12 Jan 2020"
  }
]
```

In above code you can notice hotel_data is a nested array but not able see after assigning it to vuex state.

code:

```
const mutations = {
  setItem(state, item) {
    state.item.tour_location=JSON.parse(item.tour_location);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the value with stringify as `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.tour_location))`

Comment: Actually it is already in the form of string, I am doing JSON.stringify before saving it on database